# which addon is used to recognise which database is used in application using browser FF and chrome

Tags: database, firefox, browser

which addon is used to recognise which database is used in application using browser FF and chrome.

When I load any website or application I want to know which DB is used by that website and what are the query that are fired on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overarching solution for this, since each website is created differently, using its own development stack. Even so, it would be a horrible security breach if it were possible to view database details from any website. If you've ever seen a website that provided these details then you've seen an example of very poor, insecure engineering.

So to answer your question, this is simply not possible to do for any arbitrary website.